# How to read in numbers from a file in Java?

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

I am trying to read in a file and I have managed to read in the names but not the numbers after the names. I need to make these numbers not into Strings but rather into floats or doubles. TO make matters worse, there are two numbers I have to read in. Help Please? (Btw in the code I have imported the necessary things)

An example of what i Have to read in:

McDonlad's Farm , 118.8  45670

```
public class Popcorn{ 


public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException { 


             System.out.println("Enter the name of the file");
           Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
           String filename = in.next(); 
            Scanner infile = new Scanner(new FileReader( filename)); // 
            String line = "" ; 

           //to get stuff from the file reader

            while (infile.hasNextLine())
            {  line= infile.nextLine(); 

             // int endingIndex =line.indexOf(','); 
           // String fromName = line.substring(0, endingIndex); //this is to get the name of the farm 
           // if (fromName.length()>0){
           //   System.out.println (fromName);
          //  }
           // else if (fromName.length()<= 0)
            //  System.out.println(""); some of the durdling that goes on 
           // }
          while (infile.hasNextLine())
            {  
             line= infile.nextLine().trim();  // added the call to trim to remove whitespace
               if(line.length() > 0)    // test to verify the line isn't blank
               { 
                int endingIndex =line.indexOf(','); 
              String fromName = line.substring(0, endingIndex);
                 String rest = line.substring(endingIndex + 1);
               //   float numbers = Float.valueOf(rest.trim()).floatValue();
    Scanner inLine = new Scanner(rest);

               System.out.println(fromName);
              }
 }
  }
}
}
```

Comment: You know you are skipping the first line, due to the duplicate `while` loop?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your incoming files look like, but given the example "McDonlad's Farm , 118.8 45670" you could do the following:

```
...
String rest = line.substring(endingIndex + 1);
String[] sValues = rest.split("[ \t]"); // split on all spaces and tabs
double[] dValues = new double[sValues.length];
for(int i = 0; i < sValues.length; i++) {
    try {
        dValues[i] = Double.parseDouble(sValues[i]);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // some optional exceptionhandling if it's not 
        // guaranteed that all last fields contain doubles
    }
}
...
```

The `dValues`-Array should contain all desired double (or float) values.

Some additional notes: apart from what jlordo already said, your code would become more pleasant to read if you use correct indention...